# Fastlane provision profile madness

Tags: provisioning-profile, fastlane

Sorry to file an issue if I'm missing something.

I'm using a lane looking like this:

```
  desc "Submit a new Beta Build to Apple TestFlight"
  desc "This will also make sure the profile is up to date"
  lane :beta do
    ...
    # download certificate
    cert
    # download provisioning profile
    sigh
    # set profile uiid
    # https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/docs/CodeSigning.md
    ENV["PROFILE_UUID"] = lane_context[SharedValues::SIGH_UDID]
    # build
    gym(
      scheme: "Release"
    )
    pilot
  end
```

I'm keeping having the process failing after the gym step with the following error:

```
❌  Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID “8bd6dafb-2596-41d9-8907-8c012d23a5ac”, however, no such provisioning profile was found.

[19:27:21]: Exit status: 65
[19:27:21]: Invalid code signing settings
[19:27:21]: Your project defines a provisioning profile which doesn't exist on your local machine
[19:27:21]: You can use sigh (https://github.com/KrauseFx/sigh) to download and install the provisioning profile
[19:27:21]: Follow this guide: https://github.com/KrauseFx/fastlane/blob/master/docs/CodeSigning.md
```

However I can see the right profile being downloaded in my app directory. I also can find this profile in `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` and finally my Xcode project is configure to use the `uuid` downloaded by `sigh` using:

```
PROVISIONING_PROFILE = "$(PROFILE_UUID)";
```

variable dump:

```
{
    :DEFAULT_PLATFORM=>:ios, 
    :PLATFORM_NAME=>:ios, 
    :LANE_NAME=>"ios beta", 
    :GIT_REPO_WAS_CLEAN_ON_START=>true, 
    :BUILD_NUMBER=>"55", 
    :VERSION_NUMBER=>"1.0", 
    :CERT_FILE_PATH=>"/Users/xxx/Developer/xxx/56HRT5HYC6.cer", 
    :CERT_CERTIFICATE_ID=>"56HRT5HYC6", 
    :SIGH_PROFILE_PATH=>"/Users/xx/Developer/xx/AppStore_com.xx.xx.mobileprovision", 
    :SIGH_PROFILE_PATHS=>["/Users/xxx/Developer/WiredResearch/AppStore_com.xx.xx.mobileprovision"], 
    :SIGH_UDID=>"8bd6dafb-2596-41d9-8907-8c012d23a5ac", 
    :SIGH_PROFILE_TYPE=>"app-store"
 }
```

EDIT: 2015/12/04 - Adding Cert & Sigh output

```
[09:46:47]: ------------------
[09:46:47]: --- Step: cert ---
[09:46:47]: ------------------

+-------------+----------------------------------+
|             Summary for cert 1.2.6             |
+-------------+----------------------------------+
| development | false                            |
| force       | false                            |
| username    | xx@xx.com |
| output_path | .                                |
+-------------+----------------------------------+

[09:46:49]: Starting login with user 'xx@xx.com'
[09:46:53]: Successfully logged in
[09:46:56]: Found the certificate 56HRT5HYC6 (WB Technologies) which is installed on the local machine. Using this one.
[09:46:56]: Use signing certificate '56HRT5HYC6' from now on!


[09:46:57]: ------------------
[09:46:57]: --- Step: sigh ---
[09:46:57]: ------------------
+-------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|                      Summary for sigh 1.1.4                      |
+-------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| adhoc                         | false                            |
| skip_install                  | false                            |
| development                   | false                            |
| force                         | false                            |
| app_identifier                | com.xx.xx   |
| username                      | xx@xx.com |
| output_path                   | .                                |
| cert_id                       | 56HRT5HYC6                       |
| skip_fetch_profiles           | false                            |
| skip_certificate_verification | false                            |
+-------------------------------+----------------------------------+

[09:46:57]: Starting login with user 'xx@xx.com'
[09:46:58]: Successfully logged in
[09:46:58]: Fetching profiles...
[09:47:01]: Found 1 matching profile(s)
[09:47:01]: Downloading provisioning profile...
[09:47:02]: Successfully downloaded provisioning profile...
[09:47:02]: Installing provisioning profile...
/Users/hugues/Developer/xx/AppStore_com.xx.xx.mobileprovision
[09:47:02]: Setting 

Provisioning Profile type to 'app-store'
```

Comment: What are the outputs of the `cert` and `sigh` actions?

Comment: @mokagio I've edited my answer to add it. thx!

Comment: I am having the same problem. Were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using `sigh` and `cert` directly, it is recommended to use the new [match](https://github.com/fastlane/match) with [codesigning.guide](https://codesigning.guide)

Comment: Thx @KrauseFX for the answer (and for fastlane btw). I've seen this new project, but I'm working as a sole developer on the project so didn't want to setup this as I don't really need it, but if it's what it takes, I will.

Thx

Comment: @KrauseFx Quick question, my use case will make this change to match very hard to maintain as I have several Apple Developer accounts (10+) for multiple customer apps. Any suggestion on how to proceed without the need for creating so many new repos every time I have a new customer? Also, will sigh/cert be completely deprecated and abandoned in favor of match approach?

Comment: sigh and cert will always be around, as they are both used by match as the underlying tools.

Comment: @ KrauseFx I read the [CodeSigning.md](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/docs/CodeSigning.md) documentation and decided to use the deprecated $(PROFILE_UUID) environment variable method, since I have different app identifiers for different environments (alpha, beta, appstore) and specifying `$(sigh_<bundle_identifier>_<profile_type>)` in the XCode project would prevent me from using different app identifiers.
So between `match` and `gym` in my Fastfile, I added `ENV["PROFILE_UUID"] = ENV["sigh_#{app_id}_adhoc"]`.

Does that seem correct to you?